# C# Xmlserialization

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have a very very strange problem. I would like to serialize a object via xml.
Ok so I started creating a XmlSerializer and there was no error - nothing.
But if i deserialize... the properties are just not set. Another strange thing is that the xml seems to be ok.

this is a part of my code the rest are just methods...

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(TestMapper))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(TestSource))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(TestTarget))]
public abstract class ElementBase : IElement
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public IElement this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return Childs.ElementAt(index).Value;
        }
    }

    List<ElementBase> _childSerializable;
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(ElementBase))]
    public List<ElementBase> ChildSerializable
    {
        get
        {
            _childSerializable = Childs.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
            return _childSerializable;
        }
        set
        {
            _childSerializable = value;
            foreach (ElementBase element in _childSerializable)
                Childs.Add(element.Index, element);
        }
    }

    protected Dictionary<object, ElementBase> _childs;
    [XmlIgnore]
    public Dictionary<object, ElementBase> Childs
    {
        get
        {
            return _childs ?? (_childs = new Dictionary<object ,ElementBase>());
        }
        set
        {
            _childs = value;
        }
    }

    object _index = -1;
    public object Index
    {
        get
        {
            return _index;
        }
        set
        {
            _index = value;
        }
    }
```

And this is how i serialize:

```
TestTarget target = new TestTarget();
TestSource source = new TestSource() { Value = "Hallo", Index = 1};
TestSource source1 = new TestSource() { Value = " Welt", Index = 2};
TestMapper mapper = new TestMapper();
target.ConnectChild(mapper);
mapper.ConnectChild(source);
mapper.ConnectChild(source1);
target.Execute();

System.IO.MemoryStream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(target.GetType());
serializer.Serialize(memStream, target);

memStream.Position = 0;

object obj = serializer.Deserialize(memStream);
target = obj as TestTarget;

memStream.Position = 0;
Console.ReadKey();
```

Ok so now and this is the final result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TestTarget xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ChildSerializable>
    <ElementBase xsi:type="TestMapper">
      <ChildSerializable>
        <ElementBase xsi:type="TestSource">
          <ChildSerializable />
          <Index xsi:type="xsd:int">1</Index>
          <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">Hallo</Value>
        </ElementBase>
        <ElementBase xsi:type="TestSource">
          <ChildSerializable />
          <Index xsi:type="xsd:int">2</Index>
          <Value xsi:type="xsd:string"> Welt</Value>
        </ElementBase>
      </ChildSerializable>
      <Index xsi:type="xsd:int">-1</Index>
    </ElementBase>
  </ChildSerializable>
  <Index xsi:type="xsd:int">-1</Index>
</TestTarget>
```

So does anyone has any idea what happend wrong. I am working since a few hours on it but i can t find anything :((

Comment: I suggest that you create a *minimal* example. Remove as much code as possible until the problem disappears. Then post the *shortest* code that can reproduce the error (but post *that* code in full).

Comment: just take a look at the ChildSerializable property. This is the only problem. Then look at the xml and tell why the ChildSerializable-Property has no items after deserializing

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be related to the fact that you are using a `List<ElementBase>`. If you use a simple array like `ElementBase[]`, the items are deserialized.

There are some explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890316/xmlserializer-deserialize-isnt-deserializing-a-listt-correctly), but nothing I found satisfactory.